# postgres safely change role login password

Tags: postgresql

Long ago, this bit of sql was ran:

`create role quibbler with login password 'xxx' noinherit;`

This role was never really needed for ongoing development, and the 'xxx' would have been populated via an environment variable (which probably didn't even exist at the time, in my local environment). Now I need to use this role, but I'm getting "password authentication failed". I suspect the password was blank or gibberish.

**How do I reset the login password of a role without changing any of its existing permissions or groups?** I am using PgAdmin 4 client. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PgAdmin, go to your DB, then click in Login/Group Roles option, right click on the user You want to modify. Then go to Definition tab and set a new password. That's all! See the image attached. Hope it helps.

[Change password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNfVM.png)

Comment: Sigh... *FACEPALM*.